# "Expected::" error in python

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7

beginning to learn python, so sorry if this is elementary. Why is the error "Expected::" calls by this code:

```
cur.execute('''SELECT error FROM WT_enercon_bawnmore WHERE error <> 0;''')
count = 0
for key in d:
    for i in cur:
        if key = i:
            count += 1
    d[key] = count
```

Eclipse is indicating that the fifth line is the route of the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if key == i` equality, not assignment `=`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to write:

```
if key == i:
```

Since you check it, not assigning it.

Answer (score 2):

When programming in Python, you use `'='` to assign values to the variable, if you want to compare you have to use `'=='`

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is stating that it expected to get an expression it could evaluate. Instead it sees that you are trying to make a variable assignment in your `if` statement.

```
key = i # assign i to key
key == i # evaluate equality of i and key
```

An `if` statement expects something that can be evaluated to either `True` or `False`, like `key == i`.